# Is there a way to read a local netcdf file from a web application?

Tags: javascript, local, netcdf

We are building a web service for data analysis and would like to access netcdf files from the local machine where the browser is running. Javascript offers a file browser, but (for security reasons as I learned) it will automatically upload a file after selection, instead of allowing (read-only) access to it. This presents a show-stopper, because the netcdf files can be **HUGE**. Note, that the netcdf format and API explicitly allow slicing and extraction of individual variables, which is one reason why the format is so popular.

Now, some research into this issue revealed that the server-client architecture normally doesn't allow access to the local file structure to prevent spying. On the other hand, in HTML5 there is a file API which supports exactly the kind of operations we need -- except that you can access portions of a file by specifying byte ranges, but there is no netcdf API available; hence one would be left again with copying the entire file before being able to slice it on the server.

Of course, the other option are web services such as OpenDAP which are meant to do exactly what we want, i.e. access parts of a netcdf file over the internet. However, this of course requires that every user would have to install the OpenDAP server before they could access their local files from within the web service. (Or, at a minimum they would have to install a web server so that one could access the file via `http://localhost/...`).

So: does anyone know of a solution to read specific portions of a local netcdf file from a web application? Specifically, are there javascript tools available for this?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with netcdf but you should really note that there's a strong security concern behind allowing an automated tool to access local storage, which is why all browsers prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Currently you can use [netcdfjs](https://github.com/cheminfo-js/netcdfjs), that it's a javascript library that allows to read NetCDF v3 files. Because it's a NodeJS package you can run it server side, and for regular size files you can read it online, here you have an [example](http://www.cheminfo.org/Spectra/Utilities/NetCDF_explorer/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are no Javascript tools to read NetCDF, but there are Java libraries: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf/index.jsp.

You could deploy a Java Applet to read the NetCDF file locally. From there you could have the Applet try to process the file, or communicate with a backend service, or even try to call on the Applet from Javascript: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html.

Comment: https://github.com/cheminfo-js/netcdfjs and https://github.com/metocean/netcdfjs exist now

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific Javascript libs for reading NetCDF, as far as I know. But let me drop some thoughts:

- As you say, you can install a local webserver, and use a server-side language to execute a program that reads the file in your disk. You could use a command-line software called [ncdump-json](https://github.com/jllodra/ncdump-json). I intentionally wrote this software for that purpose.
- You say that you don't want to install software like OpenDAP or webservers, but maybe a desktop app, a standalone .exe would be OK for you. Using node.js plus chromium (this is called nw.js) you have a program that is at the same time a nodejs server, and a chromium browser. This way you can write a web application that reads the data (e.g. using the embedded nodejs server and spawning ncdump-json...).
- And now the simplest scenario, a 100% client-side solution... I think this can only be achieved using Javascript... or anything that can "compile to" Javascript. We need to have the netCDF libraries in Javascript, is that possible? I guess so. [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) is a LLVM-to-Javascript compiler, and netCDF is C so it has to be possible to compile it with clang/LLVM, therefore it has to be possible to use Emscripten to have a netCDF JS library version with almost no effort, without having to write from scratch (and also maintain) a JS port. If I'm not wrong, to random access the files there's the method [slice](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#slice-method-algo) in the html5 file api, so that should not be a problem.

Hope I helped.

Comment: github.com/cheminfo-js/netcdfjs and github.com/metocean/netcdfjs exist now